# azure devops builds created with terraform wont trigger on push to master branch

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have terraform script which creates a azure devops prject a build definition and a service endpoint for github.

```
resource "azuredevops_serviceendpoint_github" "github_serviceendpoint" {
  project_id             = azuredevops_project.project.id
  service_endpoint_name  = "GitHub Service Connection"
  github_service_endpoint_pat = var.GITHUB_TOKEN
}


resource "azuredevops_build_definition" "nightly_build" {
  project_id      = azuredevops_project.project.id
  agent_pool_name = "Hosted Ubuntu 1604"
  name            = "Nightly Build"
  path            = "\\"

  repository {
    repo_type             = "GitHub"
    repo_name             = "iojas/django_ci_cd"
    branch_name           = "master"
    yml_path              = "azure-pipelines.yml"
    service_connection_id = azuredevops_serviceendpoint_github.github_serviceendpoint.id
  }
}
```

This reflects all the resources in azure devops console but pushes to master branch does not trigger the build.

I have following trigger setup in `azure-pipelines.yml`

```
trigger:
- master
```

Now if I create the same resources using azure console a build gets triggered on every push to master.

I am not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: Did you ever checked the definition that created by the terraform script? Any difference between the work one? In addition, you said you create the same resource using the azure console, using azure cli? With what commands?

Comment: I created them using azure console, by clicking the buttons, without actually running any commands. @MerlinLiang-MSFT

Comment: Okay, this must not have issue or it will be the issue on our side:-) So, did you ever check the definition that terraform script generated? Anything different?  It's better if you can download the pipeline as json and share it here(just cover some sensitive info).

Comment: I guess I found the root cause here, There is a trigger `continuous integration trigger` which is disabled by default. I could not find any way to automatically enable it upon creation of build using terraform. @MerlinLiang-MSFT. Thanks a lot for your help.